# Jest Enzyme React Native react-native-gesture-handler Problem

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, native, enzyme, react-native-gesture-handler

I am not able to test react native App using enzyme, jest, and react-native-testing-library.

with just rendring test

```
it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />).toJSON;
});
```

i get this error

FAIL  **tests**/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Direction' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/Directions.js:3:33)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/GestureHandler.js:2:42)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.586s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add this to your `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Not works here!
I Got this error https://wtools.io/paste-code/b2TO